# people who clicked on the last 4 emails and did not buy

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I need to make a sql to get the subscribers that clicked on the last four emails I sent and did NOT make a purchase.

it is a simple sql I know, I have tried several ways but it is not returning data in my data extension, I tried running it separately, the problem seems to be when it tries to fetch the specific jobIds I need, here is the last version I tried:

```
    SELECT c.SubscriberKey, c.EmailAddress, c.FirstName, c.LastName

    FROM [Contacts_v1] as c

    JOIN 

    _click as cl

    ON

    c.subscriberkey=cl.subscriberkey

    JOIN 

    _Job as j 

    ON 

    j.jobid=cl.jobid

    WHERE c.subscriberkey NOT IN (SELECT subscriberkey from [Purchasing])

    and j.Jobid In ('12234', '12414', '93493', '12425')
```

could you please help me find out what is wrong with this query and why it is not returning the data I need?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that _Clicks for a particular set of JobIDs is the smaller data set, so I'd start there.  Then you can Join to `Contacts_v1` and check `Purchasing`.

JobID is an integer/bigint.

```sql
select 
  c.SubscriberKey
, c.EmailAddress
, c.FirstName
, c.LastName
from _Click as cl
inner join Contacts_v1 as c on c.subscriberkey = cl.subscriberkey
where 1=1
and cl.jobid in (12234,12414,93493,12425)
and cl.isunique = 1
and not exists (

  select top 1 p.*
  from Purchasing as p
  where 1=1
  and p.subscriberkey = cl.subscriberkey

)
```